# Armazenar dado SQL numa Array javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a recebimento de dados SQL numa array em Javascript. Tenho as informações de login e tudo o mais, referente ao server, mas a questão não é a conexão, é salvar os dados numa array.
Exemplo: nomeArray[nome de usuário, email] (como requerir estas info do SQL?)

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {res.render('pages/home')})
function loginClient(){
var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
conn.connect().then(function(){
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);
    req.query("SELECT [CodCliSite],[RazaoSocial],[Email],[Pass] FROM [SITE].
[dbo].[Clientes]").then(function(recordset){
        res.contentType('application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset));
        console.log(recordset);
        conn.close();
    }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
        conn.close();
    });
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
}
return loginClient();
```

Comment: cria um objeto javascript e coloca os valores que esta entro do array, está com dificuldade na hora da atribuição?

Comment: Exatamente!!! Preciso mesmo de uma ajuda na hora da atribuição.

Comment: vc consegue pegar as variaveis no seu html ou .jsp?

Comment: sim, consigo. Mas a questão é a atribuição dos valores SQL para verificação.

Comment: Exemplo: 

no form tem dois campos, name e email.
porém preciso que as variáveis SQL NAME e EMAIL sejam capturadas numa array, para verificação...

Comment: Não confunda Java com Javascript, isso é o mesmo que confundir cachorro com cachorro-quente. São duas linguagens totalmente diferentes. Eu cheguei a fechar a sua questão como duplicata porque em Java, já temos algumas respostas para isso. Porém a sua pergunta é na verdade sobre Javascript. Já a reabri. Esse transtorno teria sido evitado se você não tivesse feito essa confusão.

Comment: Obrigado por reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, saberia me dizer alguma solução?

Comment: @LeonardoMatiazzo Não, não conheço o suficiente de SQL em Javascript para isso. Está a usar node.js?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, sim estou! O problema é realizar esta conexão...

Answer (score 1):

Como não tenho reputação para comentar, vou responder :)

Esse objeto **sql** que você está usando é qual lib?
Pelas chamadas parece ser o mssql. 
Esta: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql

Se for, a função de callback do método Result.query recebe dois parâmetros: (err, recordset)

No seu caso, você definiu só o **recordset** no lugar do **err**
Altera este trecho para ficar como o exemplo abaixo e vê se resolve:

```
.then(function(err, recordset)
```

O recordset já é um Array de collections, você não precisa criar Array manualmente depois da consulta.
Pode retornar o recordset diretamente.