# Problemas com dados node.js (Dados SQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, array, node.js

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a recebimento de dados SQL numa array em JavaScript. Tenho as informações de login e tudo o mais, referente ao server, mas a questão não é a conexão, é salvar os dados numa array. Exemplo: nomeArray[nome de usuário, email] (como requerir estas info do SQL?)

```
app.get('/',(req, res) => {res.render('pages/home')})
function loginClient(){
    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
    conn.connect().then(function(){
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("SELECT [CodCliSite],[RazaoSocial],[Email],[Pass] FROM [SITE].
        [dbo].[Clientes]").then(function(recordset){
            res.contentType('application/json');
            res.send(JSON.stringify(recordset));
            console.log(recordset);
            conn.close();
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            conn.close();
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
return loginClient();
```

Comment: O melhor seria salvar os dados em um objeto ou um array de objetos [`JSON`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Armazenar dado SQL numa Array javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276762/armazenar-dado-sql-numa-array-javascript)